# How to optimize a stored procedure that takes too long to execute?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure to generate random SMS records/events.

When inserting 1.2 million rows, the query takes hundreds of minutes

```
exec insert_random_sms 1200000
```

I've coded the stored procedure in a 'procedural' way. But, from what I see, SQL is not very efficient in this respect.

```
create proc insert_random_sms 
    @number_of_records int
as
begin
    declare @cnt int = 0;   -- loop counter
    declare @phone_id int;
    declare @dest_id int;

    while (@cnt < @number_of_records)
    begin
        declare @charge int = rand() * 100; -- will generate a random charge value between 0 and 100.
        declare @tarrif_plan int = round(rand() * 5, 0); 

        select top 1 @phone_id = phone_no 
        from tbl_phone_agenda 
        order by newid();

        select top 1 @dest_id = phone_no 
        from tbl_phone_agenda 
        order by newid();

        insert into tbl_sms (phone_id, dest_id, charge, tarrif_plan) 
        values (@phone_id, @dest_id, @charge, 
                convert(nvarchar(50), @tarrif_plan));

        set @cnt += 1;
    end
end
go
```

What is the way to optimize this stored procedure?

Comment: I take it the 2 selects inside the loop are an attempt to get 2 random `phone_no` from that table?

Comment: What if you randomly pick the start of the number and search top 1 with it? Now you'll sorting the whole table, which i assume is a big one. Number of digits to taken randomly should depend on your data / how often you miss to find anything.

Comment: Yes. It gets random phone numbers from another table that contains all the phone_no's in the network. The `tbl_phone_agenda` table contains 1.2 mil. records too.

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid idea, what instead of select top 1 ... you do select top 1000 or 10000 and handle that in a loop? -- this of course is valid only if it doesn't matter that same number doesn't come that often

Comment: I found out what was causing the long delay. It was in the way random `phone_no` are fetched from the existing table `tbl_phone_agenda `.    This statement actually: `select top 1 @phone_id = phone_no 
        from tbl_phone_agenda 
        order by newid();`

Comment: The NEWID() system function doesn't work well on very large tables.  Turns out, that at every iteration of the while loop, the `tbl_phone_agenda` table was sorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method I like to use for generating x number of records is the stacked CTE method (having read [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) by Aaron Bertrand who credits Itzik Ben-Gan for the stacked CTE approach):

```
WITH N1 (N) AS 
(   SELECT 1 
    FROM (VALUES 
            (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), 
            (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
        ) n (Number)
),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
N4 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM N4
```

This simply starts of with 10 rows, and keeps cross joining, until in the case of the above there are 100,000,000 rows. This would be how I would generate your rows,

When you are using a set based approach you can no longer use `RAND()` on its own because it is a run time constant, in order to get a new evaluation for each row you need to combine `RAND()` with `NEWID()` which is unique per row, so the following will generate a random number between 0 and 100 that is different for each row:

```
SELECT  CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100, 0) AS INT)
```

The next thing I would do is put all your phonenumbers into a temp table so that they have a sequential ID (this will be used to allocate randomly):

```
CREATE TABLE #Phone
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PhoneNo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT #Phone (PhoneNo)
SELECT PhoneNo 
FROM tbl_phone_agenda;
```

So your final query will be

```
CREATE PROC insert_random_sms @number_of_records IN
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Phone
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        PhoneNo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT #Phone (PhoneNo)
    SELECT PhoneNo 
    FROM tbl_phone_agenda;

    -- NEEDED SO WE KNOW WHAT NUMBER TO GENERATE A RANDOM
    -- NUMBER IN THE RIGHT RANGE LATER
    DECLARE @PhoneCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Phone);

    WITH N1 (N) AS 
    (   SELECT 1 
        FROM (VALUES 
                (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), 
                (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)
            ) n (Number)
    ),
    N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
    N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
    N4 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N3 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N2)

    INSERT tbl_sms (phone_id, dest_id, charge, tarrif_plan) 
    SELECT  TOP (@number_of_records)
            p.PhoneNo,
            d.PhoneNo,
            Charge = CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100, 0) AS INT),
            tarrif_plan = CAST(ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 5, 0) AS INT)
    FROM    N4
            INNER JOIN #Phone p
                ON p.ID = CAST(CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * @PhoneCount) AS INT)
            INNER JOIN #Phone d
                ON d.ID = CAST(CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * @PhoneCount) AS INT)

END
```

In my tests this ran in about 20-30 seconds to generate 1.2m records, looking up against 100,000 phone numbers.

Comment: nice solution, but this will only work if there are no gaps in the phone id column

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Considering the table `#Phone` is created in the procedure with its own identity column I can't see how there would be any gaps?

Comment: I realize that, but i am assuming you want this to work on the data in the question

Comment: Why wouldn't this work on the data in the question? I insert to `#phone` from `tbl_phone_agenda`, so all the phone numbers are there, they have just been allocated an identity to avoid the problem you speak of - gaps. It was either this, or use `ROW_NUMBER` to dynamically generate the sequence, but I think the temp table will perform better since the ID column is needed twice.I have used no pseudo code, the procedure as I have written it should work as intended.

Comment: I see it now, sorry. Nice job

Answer (score 0):

With a minor change in the way `random phone_no` are fetched from the existing table `tbl_phone_agenda`, I've achived the insertion of 1.2 million records in ~50 sec. No doubt that GarethD's solution is the fastest, though.

```
-- create stored procedure to insert random records into the sms table,     automatically   |   tried and tested
create proc insert_random_sms @number_of_records int
as
begin
declare @cnt int = 0;   -- loop counter
declare @phone_id int;
declare @dest_id int;
while (@cnt < @number_of_records)
    begin
        declare @charge int = rand() * 100; -- will generate a random charge value between 0 and 100.
        declare @tarrif_plan int = round(rand() * 5, 0); 
        -- here come the changes
        select top 1 @phone_id = phone_no from tbl_phone_agenda where (abs(cast((binary_checksum(*) * rand()) as int)) % 100) < 10
        select top 1 @dest_id = phone_no from tbl_phone_agenda where (abs(cast((binary_checksum(*) * rand()) as int)) % 100) < 10
        insert into tbl_sms (phone_id, dest_id, charge, tariff_plan) values (@phone_id, @dest_id, @charge , convert(nvarchar(50), @tarrif_plan));
    set @cnt += 1;
    end
end
go
```

The inspiration for my solution can be found here: [MSDN article - Selecting Rows Randomly from a Large Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx)